# ios Pop-up ask for location permission display non stop until I turn of my iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, popup, cllocationmanager, ios11

I have an issue when converting my app from 32bit to 64bit for iOS 11.
At the first time of install, it doesn't ask permission to get the location.
Then my app can't get permission. After searching I add key "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription" then it worked.

But when build to release app I try to install then confirm again get an issue that pop-up is displayed multi times like it is in the loop. This happens is not appear on a simulator. For detail, you can check at [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fnzvmwIGDIQ)

**I check on the same device in debugging it just show one time, but with archive IPA file this issue will show-up.**

Info.plist

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
```

Call startUpdatingLocation method at.

```
(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
switch (status) {
    case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways:
    case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse:
        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        break;
     default:
        break;
}
```

}

Method didUpdateToLocation

```
(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
//NSLog(@"Location:%@", newLocation);
[location release];
[locationDate release];
location = [newLocation retain];
locationDate = [[NSDate date] retain];
[locationDelegate locationSucceed:self];

if (isOneStop) {
    [self performSelector:@selector(locationRelease) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];
}
```

}

Source code call "requestAlwaysAuthorization".

```
- (void)startLocation:(NSObject<EpLocationDelegate>*)delegate {
      NSLog(@"startLocation");
      [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

      [locationDelegate release];
       locationDelegate = [delegate retain];


       locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

       locationManager.delegate = self;
       locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
       locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

       float osVersion = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
       if (osVersion >= 8.0) {
           [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
      } else {
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
 }
```

}

and `startLocation` has call in function "viewWillAppear"

**Update**

I have try to call `startLocation` at `viewDidLoad`
and still can't resolved my issue.

Comment: Please show the code where you call `requestAlwaysAuthorization`

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your response.
I have update my question. `requestAlwaysAuthorization` has call at viewWillAppear method.

Comment: `viewWillAppear` is a bad place to put it.  I would suggest `viewDidLoad`.  Also, how/where is `locationManager` declared and assigned?

Comment: @Paulw11 I just update full locationManager declared and assigned on my question. all of it is in one method name `startLocation ` then I call it in `viewWillAppear`.
So now I must move `startLocation` to `viewDidLoad`. Right?

Answer (score 0):

In your info.plist file add this:

```
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string></string>
Now in your swift file, don't forget to add delegate: CLLocationManagerDelegate

In your viewDiDLoad(), add this:

locationManager = CLLocationManager()

locationManager.delegate = self

locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()

// Here you can check whether you have allowed the permission or not.

if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()
    {
        switch(CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus())
        {

        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:

            print("Authorize.")

            break

        case .notDetermined:

            print("Not determined.")

            break

        case .restricted:

            print("Restricted.")

            break

        case .denied:

            print("Denied.")
        }
    }
```